# Update nested sub document using Node.js and mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I tried to save details to my nested sub document `tertiary`.

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    title : String,
    image:String,
    bgimage:String,
    secondary:[Secondary]
});

var Secondary = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    image:String,
    bgimage:String,
    tertiary :[Tertiary]
});

var Tertiary = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String, 
    description:String,
    image:String
});
```

The code for saving my `tertiary` data is below. I have my primary object ID as well as secondary object ID.

```
Todo.findById(fields.primaryid, function (err, secondary_todo) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log("---Inside not errot----");
        console.log(fields.secondaryRefid);

        secondary_todo.secondary.findById(fields.secondaryRefid,
                                          function (err, tertiary_todo) {
            console.log("---In Secondary data----");
            console.log(tertiary_todo);
            if (!err) {
                tertiary_todo.tertiary.push({ 
                    _id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
                    title : fields.title,
                    image : fields.file,
                    description : fields.description,
                });
            }
            tertiary_todo.save();
        }); 
    }
});
```

The error I got in my terminal is

> ```
> /......./.../..../lib/utils.js:419
>     throw err;
>           ^
>   TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'findById'
> at Promise.<anonymous>
> ```

Can anybody give a quick fix. I tried and struck with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to read [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html) page in the docs describing sub docs and also the special `id()` method used to find a sub document give its id.
So instead of calling `findById` on the sub documents

```
secondary_todo.secondary.findById(fields.secondaryRefid, function (err, tertiary_todo) {  ...
```

use `id` like so

```
var tertiary_todo = secondary_todo.secondary.id(fields.secondaryRefid);
...
```

Update: Another issue is probably that your schema setup is broken as you use your child schemas before they are defined. Reorder them like that

```
var Tertiary = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String, 
    description:String,
    image:String
});

var Secondary = new mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    image:String,
    bgimage:String,
    tertiary :[Tertiary]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Todo', {
    title : String,
    image:String,
    bgimage:String,
    secondary:[Secondary]
});
```

Comment: Hi. DAXaholic . i got the following error for the code you suggested . /../../node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:419
        throw err;
              ^
TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] has no method 'id'

Comment: I found another possible issue in your code which sets up the schema - see the update and try again please

Comment: Now it works (i.e no error ) But i cant save my tertiary details .I place my code as below is there any wrong thing or else i need to change somrthing to save 
 tertiary_todo.tertiary.push({ 
  _id:  mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  title : fields.title,
        image : fields.file,
        description : fields.description,
         });

  tertiary_todo.save();

Comment: DAXaholic ,  it saves  i made a mistake in saving my tertiary. instead of tertiary_todo.save() . i used secondary_todo.save(); .
thanks for your guidence.